# How do I fragment the http request to one or more requests using mod_proxy?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I want to fragment one http requestto one or more http requests using apache proxy(i.e mod_proxy or hooking http get request message.

For example,

1. Client sends the http Get request with Content-Range : 0 - 4096bytes
2. Apache proxy server receives the this request message
3. Proxy sends the 2 http Get request messages with each Content-Range header
   one HTTP Get Request message Content-Range : 0 - 2047 
   another HTTP Get Request message Content-Range : 2048 - 4096

Is it possibe to divide one request message to one or more request messages changing the content-range header value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way with Apache to split a request on the byte level and then send part of it to one place and then part of it to another. Specifically because the breaking the request apart can well... break the request.

Also, the receiving end would now need to piece the split request back together or the proxy would have to do it.